# (After migrating to Vite) Some stacked scripts are executed before they should?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-vite

so I just migrated to Vite, and almost everything works, except... In a Blade component I'm adding a script to my scripts stack :

```php
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        myfoo();
    </script>
@endpush
```

In `app.js` I have defined

```php
window.myfoo = () => {
    console.log(111);
}
```

And I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myfoo is not defined`. It worked before with Webpack. If I call myfoo() in the console it works. If I setTimeout the call a bit it works.

Of course in my layout they're in the correct order :

```php
@vite('resources/js/app.js') {{-- Previously <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
@stack('scripts')
```

I can force the call to wait for `DOMContentLoaded` but honestly I just don't understand the issue. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's because the script is tagged as type="module", its execution seems to be delayed. The solution is to makr the depending script as type="module" too.

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="module">
        myfoo();
    </script>
@endpush
```